# How to set DD-WRT uDHCPd PXE boot? (no DNSmasq)

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

How to setup DD-WRT standard DHCP (uDHCPd) option 66,67 ? I don't want to use DNSmasq (specific setup). According to documentation:

```
option tftp 192.168.3.210
option bootfile pxelinux.0
```

or

```
dhcp-option=66,"192.168.3.210"
dhcp-option=67,"pxelinux.0"
```

should work, but i can only make it work if DNSmasq is enabled for DHCP. Is it possible to configure uDHCPd in DD-WRT web interface?
[image]